# Nesting already created matplotlib figures to a new one

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

Is there a way to nest already created figures inside a new figure in matplotlib so that they appear side to side?

Here is how I create my figures. I use pypianoroll library to plot my figures. `generate_random_multitrack` is just to create random examples.

```
import numpy as np
from pypianoroll import Multitrack, Track

def generate_random_multitrack():
    prs = np.random.randint(128, size=(3, 16, 128))
    tracks = []
    for pr in prs:
        tracks.append(
            Track(pianoroll=pr)
        )
    return Multitrack(tracks=tracks)
mt1 = generate_random_multitrack()
mt2 = generate_random_multitrack()
```

for example `mt1.plot()` returns a list of axes and creates this figure
[image]

I would like to have something like this, where mt1 is on the left, mt2 is on the right
[image]

I can access the figures and axes created by `.plot` call with

```
axes1 = mt1.plot()
fig1 = plt.gcf()
axes2 = mt2.plot()
fig2 = plt.gcf()
```

Is there a way to nest these two figures in a new matplotlib figure side to side?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
# ... Can I nest fig1 and fig2 side to side inside fig?
```

Thanks in advance for your help and comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [their documentation](https://salu133445.github.io/pypianoroll/visualization.html), `pypianoroll` supports the `axes` argument. So, you could define your plot layout and fill the subplots with the tracks, e.g.,

```
import numpy as np
from pypianoroll import Multitrack, Track
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def generate_random_multitrack():
    prs = np.random.randint(128, size=(3, 16, 128))
    tracks = []
    for pr in prs:
        tracks.append(
            Track(pianoroll=pr)
        )
    return Multitrack(tracks=tracks)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 2, sharex=True)

mt1 = generate_random_multitrack()
mt2 = generate_random_multitrack()

mt1.plot(axs=axes.flat[::2])
mt2.plot(axs=axes.flat[1::2])
plt.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]